# Zero-dimensional $F$-space which is not strongly zero-dimensional

Tags: gn.general-topology

Does anyone know of an example of a (Tychonoff) $F$-space which is zero-dimensional but not strongly zero-dimensional?

By an $F$-space we mean every cozeroset is $C^*$-embedded.

By zero-dimensional we mean has a base of clopen sets.

By strongly zero-dimensional we mean every cozeroset is a countable union of clopen sets.

Comment: +1. If I remember correctly, I have at a conference heard Alan Dow refer to this problem as an open problem.

Comment: Yes to my knowledge it is. As I am new here I figured this might be a good place to say it to see if anybody has any ideas about it. (Let me know if this is not appropriate.)

Comment: I personally think this is a very good question for mathoverflow and it is very interesting to me as are most questions about zero-dimensional spaces which are not strongly zero-dimensional. By the way, welcome to mathoverflow.

Answer (score 9):

Alan Dow and I constructed an example.
It can be found by [following this link](https://fa.ewi.tudelft.nl/%7Ehart/37/publications/the_papers/zero-dim-F-prelim.pdf).
The construction is based on the locally compact modification of Dowker's example [in this answer](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/93719).
The final version of the example is now available on [Arxiv.org](https://arxiv.org/abs/2108.12903) and in [Topology and its Applications](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.topol.2022.108042)